# 64bit (Long) hash of a string in Scala

Tags: scala, hash, string-hashing

I need a uniform string hash that produces longs, for use in a bloom filter. Where can I find an algorithm or a library for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what `String.hashCode` does, just using longs:

```
 val code = string.foldLeft(0L) { case (code, c) => 31*code + c }
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with hashing, will this ensure an even distribution among the full range of long values?

Comment: I don't see why not, unless your strings are extremely short (like shorter than 10 characters) ... in which case, it might make sense to just store them directly rather than hashing.